# How to use same textbox with other tabs on the tabcontrol?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio

Sorry for the simple question and also sorry if there is an answer on the site and I couldn't find.

I want to use same textbox in every tab that I use on my form. How can I do that?

Comment: Add the same control to the `MyTabControls.Tab[0].Controls` collection. No doubt this will cause side affects - e.g. when you move the control on the main form, it's position will change in each of the tabs.

Comment: Don't.  Use a new TextBox for every tab.  Or else move the current TextBox outside of the TabControl since it clearly doesn't belong.

Comment: Ideally you would just move the textbox out of the Tabstrip so that it doesn't really matter which tab you are looking at. I don't think you would want to move the Textbox around every time you change tabs.

Comment: I would agree with @LarsTech: obviously, if you are using the TextBox on multiple tabs as on the main form, then the TextBox belongs on none of them and should be visible and accessible in a control outside of them.

Comment: If you absolutely have to put the textbox in the tab control, you should probably create one in each tab. You could make it so that when one of them updates, the new value is set to each textbox. That would make it appear to be the same textbox.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add this to the `TabControl`'s `SelectedIndexChanged` event handler.

```
private void tabControl1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    tabControl1.TabPages[tabControl1.SelectedIndex].Controls.Add(textBox1);
}
```

Adding a control to one tab page's `Controls` collection automatically removes it from the others.

---

Note: I have tested it by adding two lables on the form above the tab control and added these two lines to the method shown above:

```
label1.Text = tabControl1.TabPages[0].Controls.Count.ToString();
label2.Text = tabControl1.TabPages[1].Controls.Count.ToString();
```

Answer (score 1):

Put the TextBox in the parent control of the TabControl. It can hover over all the rest. You might need to rework the focus traversal though.